# Find last column number where condition is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following 2D array, where ones are always on the left:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0]
])
```

How can I find the indices of the most recent occurrence of the 1 in each row?

My expected result would be:

```
array([2, 0, 1, 3, 0])
```

Comment: Is `[1, 1, 0, 1]` possible in your array? What you except to get in this case?

Comment: @Ashenguard This case is excluded. There are no 0 between 1. 1 is always on the left.

Comment: Just an idea, The row sum minus 1 is what you need! `Sum(row) - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have a 1 in each row use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) on the reversed array:

```
# if only 0/1
out = arr.shape[1] - np.argmax(arr[:, ::-1], axis=1) -1

# else
out = arr.shape[1] - np.argmax(arr[:, ::-1] == 1, axis=1) -1
```

Output: `array([2, 0, 1, 3, 0])`

If you can have rows without 1:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
])

m = arr[:, ::-1] == 1
out = arr.shape[1] - np.argmax(arr[:, ::-1], axis=1) -1

out = np.where(m.any(1), out, np.nan)
```

Output: `array([ 2.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  0., nan])`

Answer (score 1):

With 2 loops, you can achieve what you need...

```py
result = []

for row in arr:
    last = -1  # if there is no 1
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == 1:
            last = i
    
    result.append(last)
```

Result will be a list, but you can change the result type to anything you like, for example, the NumPy array or etc

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the indices where 1 is present by:

```
k = np.where(arr == 1)

(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4], dtype=int64),  #This gives the row number 
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int64))  #This gives the index
```

To find the latest occurrence of 1 in each row:

```
[k[1][x] for x in range(len(k[0])-1) if k[0][x]!= k[0][x+1]]

#output

[2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) for a dirty one-liner. I think it's also very intuitive to use np.max() and np.where().

```
arr = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0]
])

indices = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: np.max(np.where(row == 1)),axis=1,arr=arr)

print(indices)
```

Result:

```
[2 0 1 2 3 0]
```

You can also reverse the array and use np.min instead and check if they match or not to determine if there are any case like [1, 1, 0, 1]. Please check the numpy documentation since they have a lot of examples of using these functions.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cumsum` and `argmax`:

```
np.argmax(np.cumsum(arr, axis=1), axis=1)
```

Ouput:

```
array([2, 0, 1, 3, 0])
```